# How to merge line with single word with next line?

Tags: python, bash, indentation

The code I work is mixed type of function declarations. 1) using old style of function declaration i.e. function name is followed by function type on previous line but not in same line and 2) function type and function name in single lint.

I want to change all function declarations so that function type and function name are on same line.

Reason:
The gnu "indent" is not putting the function type in same line with function name even though I am using -npsl. Also if there are new lines between function type and function name then those new lines are also not getting removed.

So I am looking for a simple bash or python command which can simply combine function type with function name. Once this is done I can use gnu indent to indent rest.

input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Record
{
    int a;
    string b;
} Record;


void 
putname
(int a, string name)


{
    // do something...
}

float fun1(int integerintegerinteger, float floatfloatfloatfloat,
    double doubledoubledoubledoubledouble, 
char yaroyarogeecheehodahaaluhaneyabaraha,
string illibaribeda

)
{  /* do nothing */ }

Record
fun3() {
    // do something else
}
```

Expected output:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Record
{
    int a;
    string b;
} Record;


void putname (int a, string name)
{
    // do something...
}

float fun1(int integerintegerinteger, float floatfloatfloatfloat, double doubledoubledoubledoubledouble, char yaroyarogeecheehodahaaluhaneyabaraha, string illibaribeda)
{  /* do nothing */ }

Record fun3() 
{
    // do something else
}
```

Is it possible to get this done in single sed or python command?

Comment: How about `indent` ? The code style you'd like is pretty configurable.

Comment: The GNU indent is not merging function type with function name. I use blow options for gnu indent `indent`.    -bad -bap -nbc -bbo -bl -bli2 -brs -ncdb -nce -cp1 -cs -di2
-ndj -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i2 -ip5 -lp -pcs -nprs -npsl -saf -sai
-saw -nsc -sob -br -ce -blf -nss -ts4 -nut -l400

Comment: OK, you might want to have a look at `astyle`. I use it to format java code, but it is able to format C code as well. `astyle --style=linux -t8 -n` is my setting, yielding a format that Linus would accept.

Comment: even `astyle --style=linux -t8 -n` is not indenting. Tried in input file shared above. I don't understand what is missing!

Comment: If I find the time (tomorrow) I'll try to develop something. Can't promise anything though (the person who's paying me expects me to deliver some results every now and then). I'm disappointed about the astyle and indent results. Didn't expect that. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Apart from `astyle`, even gnu `indent` is not merging the function type and function in same line though the documentation and options mention they merge. I don't know something really missing!

Comment: you have an answer now. But since I took the effort to search the web a little, I wouldn't want to hide the results. Anyway, I found another beautifier called uncrustify (git://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify.git). After configure and make, I yielded the desired result by `src/uncrustify -c etc/sun.cfg < ../x.c | indent -bad -bap -nbc -bbo -bl -bli2 -brs -ncdb -nce -cp1 -cs -di2 -ndj -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i2 -ip5 -lp -pcs -nprs -npsl -saf -sai -saw -nsc -sob -br -ce -blf -nss -ts4 -nut -l400`. Funny enough one apparently needs 2 beautifiers to get the source beautified.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to write `sed` command that can do the job provided "there are no empty lines between function type and function name". Below is the command:

```
/^\(typedef\|using\|namespace\|#\)/ !{  #if line not starts with typedef or using or # or namespace
    /^\s*$/ !{                          #if line not an empty line
        /\(;\|)\|{\|}\)$/ !{            #if line is not ending with ; or ) or { or } 
            N;                          #read next line
            s/\n/ /                     #replace newline with space
        }
    }
}
```

oneliner:

```
sed '/^\(typedef\|using\|#\)/ !{/^\s*$/ !{/\(;\|)\|{\|}\)$/ !{N; s/\n/ /}}}' file
```

Note there could be more efficient way to do the above job. As I am a learner I found above method. It is good if anybody can optimize it.

The final indentation goes in below order:
1. used gnu `indent` to indent the code (for some reason function type is not merged with function name)
2. run above `sed` command to merge function type with function name in single line